# JS for-loop doesn't work properly. Getting inaccurate value as a 'total'

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Trying to calculate array items, but keep getting an incorrect total value. Any thoughts where can be a mistake?

```js
let input;
const numbers = [];
let total = 0;

//debugger;

do {
  input = prompt("Please, enter the number");
  if (input === null) {
    if (numbers.length > 0) {
      alert(`Total is ${total}`);
    }
    break;
  }

  input = parseInt(input);
  console.log("input: ", input);
  if (isNaN(input)) {
    continue;
  } else {
    numbers.push(input);
  }

  for (const [i, v] of numbers.entries()) {
    total = total + v;
  }

  console.log("total: ", total);
} while (input !== null);
```

Comment: Please post some example to show what input you gave and what total you got and what was the expected total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now at any step you add to the total, the new total, not replace the new total with the old one.

You can do:

```js
let input;
const numbers = [];
let total = 0;

//debugger;

do {
  input = prompt("Please, enter the number");
  if (input === null) {
    if (numbers.length > 0) {
      alert(`Total is ${total}`);
    }
    break;
  }

  input = parseInt(input);
  console.log("input: ", input);
  if (isNaN(input)) {
    continue;
  } else {
    numbers.push(input);
  }
  total=0;
  for (const [i, v] of numbers.entries()) {
    total = total + v;
  }

  console.log("total: ", total);
} while (input !== null);
```

or just:

```js
let input;
let total = 0;

//debugger;

do {
  input = prompt("Please, enter the number");
  if (input === null) {
      alert(`Total is ${total}`);
    break;
  }

  input = parseInt(input);
  console.log("input: ", input);
  if (isNaN(input)) {
    continue;
  } else {
    total += input;
  }

  console.log("total: ", total);
} while (input !== null);
```

Comment: Done...But I don't really understand, why does it happen like that - why did it iterated over the whole array?

Answer (score 1):

You're looping over the whole array every time. So every number gets added to the total not just when you enter it, but again for every later number you enter.

Imagine that you enter 1 for the first number. Then `numbers` is `[1]` and `total` is 0 going into your loop, which adds 1 to `total` to make it 1. So far, so good.

Then you enter 2. Now going into your loop we have `total` as 1 and `numbers` as `[1,2]`, so your loop adds add 1 and 2 to the previous value of 1 and sets `total` to 4 instead of 3.

Then you enter 3. Going into the loop this time, `total` is 4 and `numbers` is `[1,2,3]`. So the loop adds 1+2+3 to the previous 4 and now `total` is 10 instead of 6.

Basically, there's no need to loop because `total` already includes all the previously-entered numbers. So you can replace this loop:

```
 for (const [i, v] of numbers.entries()) {
    total = total + v;
  }
```

With this single statement:

```
  total = total + input;
```

Which can also be written like this:

```
  total += input;
```

Alternatively, since you're keeping all the entered numbers in an array, you can wait until they're all entered and then loop over that array then to add them up. But then you don't have a subtotal to display after each number.

Comment: Mark, thank you so much for clarifying everything, sorry for the stupid question, my bad...